# getting HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp

This is my form

```
<form id="profileChangeInput" action="" method="post">
    <table border="0">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="profile_input_txt"     align="right">First&    nbsp;Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="fname"
                name="j_firstname" value=""
                class="profile_input_box_fname"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="profile_input_txt" align="right">Last&nbsp;Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="lname" name="j_lastname"
                value="" class="profile_input_box_lname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="profile_input_txt" align="right">ZIP&nbsp;Code:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="zip" name="j_zipcode"
                value="" class="profile_input_box_zipcode"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="profile_input_txt" align="right">Phone&nbsp;#:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="phonenum"
                name="j_phonenum" value=""
                class="profile_input_box_phonenum"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="profile_input_txt" align="right">Year&nbsp;of&nbsp;Birth:</td>
            <td><select id="selYOB">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1950">1950</option>
                    <option value="1951">1951</option>
                    <option value="1952">1952</option>

                    <option value="2011">2011</option>
                    <option value="2012">2012</option>
            </select></td>
            <td class="profile_input_txt" align="right">Gender:</td>
            <td><select id="gender">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="profile_input_txt" align="right">Email&nbsp;Address:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="email" name="j_email"
                value="" class="profile_input_box_email"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input class="profile_btn" id="save_button"
                type="submit" value="SAVE CHANGES"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

This is how I am trying to route it to controller

```
$.post('profileChange.do', $('#profileChangeInput').serialize(), function(data) {
      alert('inside post:changes saved');
```

This is the spring controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/profileChange.do")
public class ProfileController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showProfile(@RequestParam(required=false) String rfky,Map model,HttpSession session){
    ProfileInputDTO profileInputDTO = new ProfileInputDTO();
    model.put("profileInputDTO", profileInputDTO);
    System.out.println("in showprofile method");
    return "myProfile";
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String ProcessProfileChange(ProfileInputDTO profileInputDTO,
        BindingResult result,HttpSession session)throws Exception{
    DataConverter dc = DataConverterUtil.getDefaultConverter();
    WSOutputDTO output = ProcessProfileChange(profileInputDTO, session);

    List<String> errors = output.errors;
    if (errors == null) {
        System.out.println("in success loop");
        return "success";
    } else {
        String errorsStr = "";
        for (String error : errors) {
            errorsStr += error + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println("in errir loop");
        return errorsStr;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I fail to see a question here.

Comment: Are you looking to use AJAX or a full request?  If you're going to do graceful degradation you should do it in a way that makes sense and use different endpoints.  If you're looking for Ajax then you probable want a `@RequestBody` and no `BindingResult`

Comment: No I am not using AJAX here

Comment: John, Thanks for editing

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying for an ajax submit, if so change your `ProfileInputDTO profileInputDTO` to `@RequestBody ProfileInputDTO profileInputDTO` and remove `BindingResult result`